# Conditionally move values between columns

Tags: sql-server, function, case

I have the following record set output:

```
   ID     Name          Pay_Type    Paid_Amnt    Interest_Amnt
   1     John Smith      Benefit      1075            0
   1     John Smith      Interest      1.23           0
   2     Tom Ryder       Benefit      1123            0
   3     Mark Thompson   Benefit      1211            0
   3     Mark Thompson   Interest     1.34            0
```

What I'd like is for values with the Pay_Type = Interest to be placed in the Interest column.

Desired output:

```
   ID    Name           Pay_Type    Pay_Type 2      Paid_Amnt   Interest_Amnt
    1    John Smith       Benefit     Interest        1075      1.23
    2    Tom Ryder        Benefit       NULL          1123        0
    3    Mark Thompson    Benefit      Interest       1211       1.34
```

I tried something like the following:

```
   Select row_number()over(partition by id, case when pay_type = 'Interest' then interest_amnt = paid_amnt
                                                 when pay_type = 'Interest' then paid_amnt = 0 end) as new_interest
```

Does anyone know how to get the desired results?

Thank you

```
   declare @t table(id int, pay_type varchar(25), name varchar(100),  paid_amnt float, interest_amnt float)

   insert into @t values(1, 'Benefit', 'John Smith', 1075, 0),
                 (1, 'Interest', 'John Smith',1.23, 0),
                 (2, 'Benefit', 'Tom Ryder', 1123, 0),
                 (3, 'Benefit', 'Mark Thompson', 1211, 0),
                 (4, 'Interest', 'Mark Thompson', 1.34, 0)

    select * from @t
```

Comment: Are there only at most 2 records per user? Or could John Smith possibly have 2 interest records and 2 benefit records ? If there can be more than 2, are you wanting to to sum the values of Benefits and Interest for each user?

Comment: Good question.  As far as I can tell there are only 2 records per user, but I don't know for sure if there are more.  But yes, I want to sum the values of Benefits and Interest for each user onto one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you can have more than 2 records per person, I believe this will give you what you want, it utilizes a couple of subqueries and group by,

**subquery x** groups your records so you get the interest sums and benefits sums in a row per user,

**subquery y** uses `CASE` expressions to place the summed amounts into their proper columns or zero in case of it being Benefit/Interest and adds the pay type columns of pay_type1 and pay_type2 with values of Benefit and Interest respectively,

**outer query** groups everything together into 1 row per user, and sums their interest and benefit columns respectively:

```
SELECT y.[id] AS [ID], y.[name] AS [Name], 
       y.[pay_type1] AS [Pay_Type], y.[Pay_Type2], SUM(y.[Paid_Amnt]) AS [Paid_Amnt], 
       SUM(y.[Interest_Amnt]) AS [Interest_Amnt]
FROM
(
    SELECT id, name, 'Benefit' AS [pay_type1], 'Interest' AS [pay_type2],
           CASE WHEN pay_type = 'Benefit' THEN x.Amount ELSE 0 END AS [Paid_Amnt], 
           CASE WHEN pay_type = 'Interest' THEN x.Amount ELSE 0 END AS [Interest_Amnt] 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, pay_type, name, SUM(paid_amnt) AS [Amount]
        FROM table as t
        GROUP BY id, pay_type, name
    ) AS x
) AS y
GROUP BY y.[id], y.[name], y.[pay_type1], y.[pay_type2]
```

Comment: This is still giving me 2 lines per name.  Do you know how to put it all on one line?

Comment: @jackstraw22 This should give you one row per user, I think I had failed to do the aggregates on the last two columns in the outer query and remove them from the outer group by. Please see updated answer. Sorry about that, I wrote this as psuedo and didn't run any tests against it.